# Mysql Query for advance search

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table "students" and this table has text column "description". This column contains student profile.  Now, let suppose, we have 2 words a) Lorem b) ipsum.

We want to get all student in which these words will follow this criteria:
   a. Description must contain word: lorem
   b. Just after "lorem" word, in the next 20 characters, if there is other word "ipsum" exists, then mysql return me that student.

I have average knowledge of Mysql, but not able to make a query that can follow above criteria. Can someone please share a mysql query through which I can get records based on above conditions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
where description regexp 'lorem.{0,19}ipsum'
```

It is unclear if you want all of `'ipsum'` in the next 20 characters or to just start.  This assumes that you want it to start in the next 20.  You can adjust the `19` if you want more of `ipsum` in the 20 characters.

If you want an exact match for words, use word delimiters:

```
where description regexp 'lorem.{0,19}[^a-zA-Z]ipsum[^a-zA-Z]'
```

You might have a better expression for word delimiters.  MySQL has switched regular expression libraries recently, so I'm hesitant to use anything like `\b`.

Comment: Thanks I just want to search my 2nd keyword in only in next 20 characters, no matter if it is repeated or not. But it it exists then record should come. I Have also check with some test cases. If my description contain text like "sdsgd lorem ipsdsds", then system is fetching this record. I want only those records in which exact match found for 2nd word.